# Workaround for incorrect Resharper 9/TypeScript error?

Tags: typescript, resharper, resharper-9.0

I just installed Resharper 9, and I'm liking its improved Typescript support quite a bit. But I'm running into an error in scenarios like this:

```
module Test {
    export function sayHello() {
        alert('Hi!');
    }
}

Test.sayHello = () => console.log('Hi!');
```

That's a perfectly valid bit of Typescript syntax (it compiles and runs without any errors or warnings), and is very handy for mocking scenarios and so forth. However, Resharper 9 is flagging the last line as an error:

```
The left hand side of an assignment expression must be a variable, property or indexer.
```

Now, Resharper isn't the TS compiler, so in theory I can just ignore the error, but when there are dozens of these inaccurate error assessments in one of my files, it's hiding legitimate errors.

I haven't been able to figure out how to turn off just this bit of error checking. I've reported this as a bug, and presumably they'll fix it eventually, but in the meantime, it's quite distracting.

Any suggestions for a workaround, shy of going back to Resharper 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no workaround is available, sorry. Thanks a lot for your report, I've created an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-428835. Will be fixed in the first bugfix update for 9.0.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to it.

Comment: By the way, Resharper 9.01 is out now, and I can confirm that it fixes this problem.